# Launch app on iPad in 2x mode with iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

Before iOS 7, iPhone apps that opened on iPads used to launch in 2x mode. iOS 7 seems to force all apps, even if they weren't designed for the iPad, to launch in 1x mode. How can we force our app to launch in 2x mode on iPads using iOS 7?

Comment: What happened with the accept here? Is there a misunderstanding as to the nature of the question?

Comment: You're right, the specific question was answered. We posted the solution to the root cause of our issue, not the symptom (which is this question). Reverted the accept. Wow, you're fast!

Comment: Ah gotcha. Just happened to check SO at the right time and wanted to see if there was something I could do to fix the unaccept. ;-) I think I saw your other answer briefly, but then it disappeared, leaving me a bit confused. :-)

Comment: Someone deleted our answer for some reason. While it didn't directly address the question, it was still very much related and addressed the underlying issue as opposed to the symptom. Anyway, you still get credit!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

iPhone apps on iPads running iOS 7 now always open as a Retina iPhone app, while on iOS 6 they opened as a non-retina apps on non-retina iPads.

On Retina iPads (iPad 3 and 4) the apps may display in 1x (iPhone sized) or 2x (taking as much of the iPad screen as possible) and may be toggled.

On non-Retina iPads (iPad 2 and iPad mini) the apps only display in 2x mode and cannot be toggled. This is because the non-retina iPads do not have enough pixel density to display the retina iPhone apps at the "normal" size.

This behavior is determined by the OS and cannot be changed by your app.