# iPhone app appearance differences--simulator to iPad deployment

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, deployment

I just deployed my iPhone app to my iPad 2 (only iOS device I've got) and was surprised to see these differences in how each system displays the thing:

[image]

I've already had the truncation question answered in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195221/differences-in-simulator-vs-deployment-on-ipad), but can anyone tell me what's up with the button text underlining and the bar button backgrounds? I'm coding with Xcode 5.1.1, iOS 7 SDK. The non-retina iPad is running iOS 7.1.2.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I should note my observation that the dark colored bar buttons appear only in modal VCs

Comment: First, it seems like you already accepted an answer there. Second, can you show some code especially on the part how to make the underline.

Comment: I accepted the answer on my first (different, separate) question because it answered the question I asked about the truncated display, as noted above. As to the underline I'm asking about here, the crux of my question is that there ISN'T any code specifying an underline. It appears only in the iPad deployment of the app. I'm happy to show any code, but on the ipad, this underlining phenomenon appears on all non-bar buttons in the app, all of which were created in my storyboard, and none of which have any code specifying an underline.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer to this curiosity in the [first answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124277/some-texts-automatically-underlined-in-iphone-5-with-ios-7-1):

It's an iOS 7.1 Accessibility thing (Button Shapes turned on) that causes both the aberrations mentioned in my question, apparently not reflected in the SDK I'm using.

Thanks for looking! Just wasn't obvious to me since this is my first time to deploy on a device. Hopefully will be beneficial to others.